# Intersecting rows of Numpy 2d Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to get the indices of the intersecting rows of a main numpy 2d array A, with another 3 arrays B, C and D, and return another array E with that indices
Example:

```
A = array([[1,1],
           [2,3],
           [2,4],
           [3,4],
           [3,5],
           [3,6],
           [4,5],
           [5,6]])

B = array([[2,3],
           [4,3],
           [3,5]])

C = array([[3,4],
           [3,5],
           [5,6]])

D = array([[4,2],
           [5,4],
           [6,3]])
RESULT ARRAY:
[[1, 3, -2],
 [-3, 4, -6],
 [4, 7, -5]]
```

Note that when the columns are reversed the result of indice must assume (-)

Exemple intersecting A and B:

```
A = array([[1,1],
           [2,3],
           [2,4],
           [3,4],
           [3,5],
           [3,6],
           [4,5],
           [5,6]])

B = array([[2,3],
           [4,3],
           [3,5]])

RESULT ARRAY:
[1, -3, 4]
```

Intersecting row B: [4,3] with A: [3,4], return result -3, because the intersecting row are reversed

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a solution that you don't like for some reason?  Please post it and explain its deficiencies.

Comment: Someone indicated the following code using numpy_indexed:

import numpy_indexed as npi
A = np.sort(A, axis=1)
B = np.sort(rs1t, axis=1)
result = npi.indices(A, B)
result *= (A[:, 0] == B[:, 0]) * 2 - 1

But it returns all values ​​(-) I do not know why

Comment: And another one suggested use of the following loop:

for i in range(0, len(A)):
    for j in range(0, len(B)):
        if A[i].tolist() == B[j].tolist():
            result.append(i)
        if A[i].tolist()[::-1] == B[j].tolist():
            result.append(-i)
print(result)

But this method is not viable, because my true matrix has about 50 thousand lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using some magic with `in1d`, if you convert the array to a record array of tuples.

```
def get_indices(a, b):
    # Convert to arrays if needed
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)

    dtype = 'int, int'

    # Get the indices
    forward = np.in1d(a.view(dtype), b.view(dtype))
    backward = np.in1d(a[:, ::-1].copy().view(dtype), b.view(dtype))

    # Compute formatting as requested
    sign = forward.astype(int) - backward.astype(int)
    value = forward | backward
    indices = np.where(value)[0]
    return indices * sign[indices]
```

Using this you could then call it for each array to get your result:

```
>>> np.hstack([get_indices(A, b)[:, None] for b in [B, C, D]])
array([[ 1,  3, -2],
       [-3,  4, -5],
       [ 4,  7, -6]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: The following error is occurring:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/matrix/d9.py", line 54, in <module>
    np.hstack([get_indices(A, b)[:, None] for b in [B, C, D]])
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/matrix/d9.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
    np.hstack([get_indices(A, b)[:, None] for b in [B, C, D]])
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/matrix/d9.py", line 45, in get_indices
    forward = np.in1d(a.view(dtype), b.view(dtype))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'view'

Comment: Added conversion to numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

Put all the elements of A into a dictionary, where the keys are rows (as tuples), and the value is the row's index. Then iterate over the rows of B, C, D, using the dictionary to lookup indices of A.

```
A = [[1,1],
     [2,3],
     [2,4],
     [3,4],
     [3,5],
     [3,6],
     [4,5],
     [5,6]]

B = [[2,3],
     [4,3],
     [3,5]]

C = [[3,4],
     [3,5],
     [5,6]]

D = [[4,2],
     [5,4],
     [6,3]]

A_dict = {tuple(pair): i for i, pair in enumerate(A)}
A_dict.update({(pair[1], pair[0]): -i for i, pair in enumerate(A)})

result_array = []
for arr in [B, C, D]:
  result_array.append([A_dict[tuple(pair)] for pair in arr])

print result_array
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion...

```
def search(Array,Main):
    lst = []
    for row in Array:
        mtc = np.where((Main == row).all(axis=1))[0]
        if len(mtc) == 0:
            mtc = np.where((np.flip(A,1) == row).all(axis=1))[0] * -1
        lst.append(mtc)
    return np.array(lst)

arrays = [search(x,A) for x in [B,C,D]]

print np.hstack(arrays)
```

giving you your array

```
[[ 1  3 -2]
 [-3  4 -6]
 [ 4  7 -5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
Notice that I use lists instead of arrays, therefore the conversion with `.tolist()`

```
def intersect(A, Blist):
    A, Blist = A.tolist(), [B.tolist() for B in Blist]
    return np.transpose( [[A.index(l) if l in A else -A.index([l[1], l[0]]) for l in L] for L in Blist] )
```

This yields

```
array([[ 1,  3, -2],
       [-3,  4, -6],
       [ 4,  7, -5]])
```

for

```
intersect(A, [B, C, D])
```